# Why is conversion between with different type parameters is NOT allowed?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, contravariance

I just don't get it as it would be so useful to convert one generic container into the other?

```
Stack <IType> stack = new Stack<SomeType>();
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about conversions like so?

```
IFoo<Child> child = ...;
IFoo<Parent> parent = child;
```

If so, this is what is known as covariance.  This is usually paired with it's counterpart contravariant.  This feature is indeed not available in the current version of C#.  But it will be available in next version of both C# and VB.Net.

Some articles about the upcoming release

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx
- http://www.leading-edge-dev.de/?p=246

Comment: Yes, this one as well as the one mentioned in the updated post. thanks

Answer (score 2):

While what @JaredPar says is true, there are some work-arounds for collections that are available today.  For instance, you can use the Cast IEnumerable extension if there is a legal cast from one type to another.

```
List<Foo> list = barList.Cast<Foo>().ToList();
```

Or you could explicitly convert from one type to another using Select.

```
List<double> dList = intList.Select( i => Convert.ToDouble( i ) ).ToList();
```

Note that both of these methods will produce a new collection of the appropriate type, not simply assign the collection to a variable of a different type as will be available under certain conditions in the next versions of C#/VB.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the example you gave:

```
Stack <IType> stack = new Stack<SomeType>();
```

What would happen if we did this:

```
stack.Add(new SomeOtherTypeNotDerivedFromSomeType());
```

This is the basic reason why covariance is not allowed in .Net, I guess because the underlying collection for the generic container does not necessarily match the declared type. The articles by Eric Lippert go into great detail (more than I really can).

Comment: It's actually allowed in IL starting with 2.0. It's just that none of the compilers take advantage of it

Comment: If casting operators could be generic, it could make sense to have code such as described be equivalent to `Stack<Itype> stack = Stack<IType>.ConvertFrom<SomeType>(new Stack<SomeType>);`, with the conversion method implying suitable constraint on `SomeType`.  It's worth noting that if `Stack<T>` is immutable, the conversion may make sense and be type-safe even if `Stack<T>` is not covariant with respect to `T` (e.g. it has a `Contains` method which accepted a `T`: testing whether a `Stack<Cat>` contains an instance of `Dog` shouldn't crash--it should just return `false`).